# Problem with Uri class in .NET Framework and special characters

Tags: .net, uri, urlencode

I have an image URL that contains a [left-to-right mark](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Left-to-right_mark) character.
That is an unprintable character that is used to set the way adjacent characters are grouped with respect to text direction.
This is the original URL: `https://simply-listening.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Toyah-‎–-Anthem.jpg`.
When URL encoding the URL you get: `https://simply-listening.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Toyah-%e2%80%8e%e2%80%93-Anthem.jpg`

It my look a little confusing:
After the `Toyah` part, there's:

- a hyphen
- the left-to-right mark (%e2%80%8e)
- an en-dash (a longer hyphen: %e2%80%93)
- a hyphen

The two hyphens will not get URL encoded but the left-to-right mark and the en-dash are.

This all is fine and you can open both the non-encoded and the encoded URLs in Chrome without problem.
The issue is when I create a Uri class instance with this URL.

```cs
new Uri("https://simply-listening.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Toyah-%e2%80%8e%e2%80%93-Anthem.jpg")
```

The created instance has a `AbsoluteUri` property with the following value:
`https://simply-listening.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Toyah-%E2%80%93-Anthem.jpg`

As you can see the left-to-right mark character is removed from the URL and the URL no longer works of course.

Is there a reason the Uri class would remove certain characters (even encoded) from a URL? I would assume that any character that's not valid in a URL could still be used as long as it's URL encoded. And browsers seem fine with it as well.

Comment: I've tried your code with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET 5 also on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and don't reproduce what you see. AbsoluteUri doesn't change.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. Seems it was fixed in .NET Framework 4.7.2. We are using 4.7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Simon Mourier's comment I found out that the issue is not showing up in .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Since we are using .NET Framework 4.7.1 I checked the changelog for 4.7.2 and there it was: ["Fixed a problem in System.Uri where Unicode bidirectional control characters would be stripped from a Uri during parsing."](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/dotnet472-changes.md#aspnet).

Looks like it was indeed a bug, and it's fixed now.